# Android garbage collector get deleted object name

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

I recently modified a bing chunk of my code and the garbage collector went crazy and I can't figure out what does it deletes. So I'd like to get the names of the things that the garbage collector deletes.

I've tried Android Device Monitor but I can't figure out where or how to find it or if it is even possible.

What should I do to figure out where to modify my code?

Comment: "I recently modified a bing chunk of my code..." - please, show your modified code and, if possible, this code before modification.

Comment: If the GC went crazy, it's because you're creating **A LOT** of objects that are not referenced anymore. You probably should check for `new` keyword in methods that get called very often like `onScroll` or `getView`

Comment: @DmitryTsechoev I can show you but It is basically opengl es 2.0 + renderscript I can upload it somewhere if you still want to see it.

Comment: I want to try. Please, upload it.

Comment: @DmitryTsechoev https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5xcsgsfjeb5ph53/AACRI9y9wdO-TkWdPUNDer8Fa?dl=0

Comment: @ZoltánNémeth, sorry, but it is difficult for me to suggest you something. I don't see the reason of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`finalize()`,

this API is provided by Java which JVM calls whenever an object is about to go through GC, although no gurantee if it will be called as per JAVA DOC, you can try printing name here.

Hope this solve ur issue.

Comment: No ... that is only going to make things worse!!

Comment: No way then, try your luck through android DDMS heap and allocation tracker tool, it does tell about about leaked, GC'ed and live.

Answer (score 0):

(Actually, if the GC has "gone crazy", a more likely problem is the objects it *can't* delete than the ones that it deletes.)

---

Firstly, objects don't (in general) have names.

Secondly, I don't think it is possible to track when the GC actually deletes objects.

So tracking object deletion is unlikely to work ... and probably wouldn't help anyway.

---

What I think you really need is a *memory profiler* tool (e.g. DDMS) that can tell you were the objects are allocated, and can help you analyse all of the objects that are live (reachable) and garbage (unreachable).

The two most likely things that can make the GC use a lot of time (or "go crazy") are:

- Having too much reachable data.  As the heap gets close to full, the percentage of time spent *attempting* to collect garbage increases dramatically.  A common cause of having too much reachable data is a storage leak in your application.
- Creating too many temporary objects.  A higher allocation rate means that the collector has to run more often.

References:

- https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html
- http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html

Comment: I don't have that much temporary things mostly a couple of floats. I store a lot of data so I checked the heap about 51% constant usage so that can't be the problem either. The object count changes constantly (7 object) that is why I wanted to check out which ones gets deleted